# Odoo filestore vs session

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I understand Odoo filestore is required for each database we have, if we are saving additional data (attachments, images and so on) outside the database itself (in the filesystem).

If we need to manually move a database to a new server (with pg_dump for instance), we also need to move the filestore.

What about the sessions? Do we need to keep the sessions folder also? Is it safe to completely remove files inside the "sessions" folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you backup Odoo DB with filestore from Odoo it's only create zip file with sql dump file and filestore folder. So you don't need to move the sessions folder content to the new server.

Comment: Hi @Walled Mohsen... you're right. Forgot about this detail. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to copy the session folder since it only contains users' login sessions. If you are okay with users having to re-login when you are done moving the server, then just leave this folder.

As an extra detail, not only is it safe to delete the contents of this folder, it's a good idea to empty the session folder daily for added security as it ensures users have to log in every day.